Which is incorrect, Nautilus (linux file explorer) or VSCode? Modified sort shows arrow pointing in different directions
When I list the folders in Nautilus (file explorer - Gnome Nautilus 46.2) on my Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS box and I click the [Modified] column so I can view the most recently modified folders & files I see the following -- notice the arrow is pointing down (highlighted in red):

However, when I open Visual Studio Code and navigate through the file system and sort with most recently modified files at the top, then VSCode shows the arrow pointing up as shown in the next snapshot (again, highlighted in red):

Uh Oh: Checked Two Other Apps & There Is No Consensus
When I open GIMP on the same system (Ubuntu 24.0.1) I see that it sorts those files the same way that VSCode does -- with the arrow pointing up when newest are at top:

And Filezilla shows the arrow the other way:


Use up or down arrow to represent "sort ascending" at table header

@GuyIncognito That's a good link, thanks.
